# Get all two-factor products of all matrix' rows columns

Tags: matlab, performance, vectorization

I have an n x m matrix. Let denote some row of this matrix as x. Each row represents a number of features `x1, x2, x3, ...`

Now,  I would like to receive the elements above the diagonal of `x * x'`, namely: `x1*x2, x1*x3, x2*x3`, ... but not `x1*x1`. Also, if I have `x1*x2`, I do not need `x2*x1`.

I want to add these columns with products to my matrix. Given that I have had `m` columns before, I will then have additional columns for these products, namely: `(m^2 + m)/2 - m` more columns.

This should be accomplished for each row of my matrix.

I have found a solution in Matlab already. However, it seems to be very slow and I am wondering whether there is a more vectorized solution available which Matlab could execute faster.

My current solution uses a package to get a vector of the elements above the upper diagonal: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23391-triangular-and-diagonal-indexing

`M(itriu(size(M),1))` of a matrix `M` will give me the elements of my matrix above the diagonal. For example, if I throw in `[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]` I will get `2 3 6` as result.

My code is as follows:

```
function [ X_out ] = permutateFeatures( X_in )
%PERMUTATEFEATURES given a matrix with m features in the columns
% and n samples in the rows, return a [n (m^2 + m)/2] matrix
% where each additional column contains a element-wise product of two of
% the original columns

n = size(X_in, 1);
m = size(X_in, 2);

X_out = [X_in zeros(n, (m^2 + m)/2 - m)];

for i = 1:n
    outerProduct = X_out(i,1:m)' * X_out(i,1:m);
    X_out(i,:) = [X_in(i,:) outerProduct(itriu(size(outerProduct),1))'];
end

end
```

Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: What are typical values for the size parameters `n` and `m`?

Comment: @Divakar `m` is rather small, mostly `<20`. `n` goes into the millions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a vectorized solution -

```
[r,c] = find(triu(true(size(X_in,2)),1));
out = [X_in X_in(:,r).*X_in(:,c)];
```

**Runtime test**

Timing code -

```
% Setup input array 
% (as stated in comments : m is mostly <20. n goes into the millions)
X_in = randi(5,[50000,20]);

disp('--------------------------- Original Solution')
tic,
n = size(X_in, 1);
m = size(X_in, 2);
X_out = [X_in zeros(n, (m^2 + m)/2 - m)];
for i = 1:n
    outerProduct = X_out(i,1:m)' * X_out(i,1:m);
    X_out(i,:) = [X_in(i,:) outerProduct(itriu(size(outerProduct),1))'];
end
toc

disp('--------------------------- Proposed Solution')
tic,
[r,c] = find(triu(true(size(X_in,2)),1));
out = [X_in X_in(:,r).*X_in(:,c)];
toc,
```

Timings -

```
--------------------------- Original Solution
Elapsed time is 8.618389 seconds.
--------------------------- Proposed Solution
Elapsed time is 0.131146 seconds.
```

Huge speedups there of **`60x+`**!

Comment: this solution also features the vectorization finding the right vectors. The diffrence is only the order of the output vectors. if you sort it by ascending `r` it is the same again

Comment: @Finn I am not sure what difference are we talking about here. Could you clarify? The output from this `out` should be identical to `X_out`.

Comment: oh my mistake. i thought the order would rowwise in the Triangular matrix (`x1*x2,x1*x3,...,x1*xm`and then `x2*x3,x2*x4,...x2*xm`), as the question isint distinct on that. But now i see in the code that it is rather columwise so your and the example have the same order and mine would have to be resorted.

Answer (score 1):

Here the matrix multiplication is vectorized which is the far bigger part of the calculation. If you want to you can vectorize the creation of vec1 and vec2 as well, but there is only little more effiency to get:

```
vec1=[];
vec2=[];
for i = 1:n
    vec1=[vec1 i*ones(1,n-i)];
    vec2=[vec2 (i+1):n];
end
X_out2=[X_in X_in(:,vec1).*X_in(:,vec2)];
```

for a `rand(1000,1000)` the old approach and this one perform

```
Elapsed time is 24.709988 seconds.
Elapsed time is 6.753230 seconds.
```

on my machine, with the same solution.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Is your code supposed to be a more efficient solution or have you condensed the code above? My solution certainly works but is slow, since my matrix has millions of rows, so it takes 5 minutes or so.

Comment: it is more efficient as the computational heavy part (the matrix multiplication) is vectorized, in regards to that i updated my answer. I was trying to say you could vectorize the creation of `vec1,vec2` that the entire loop can be removed.

Comment: the output is sorted rowwise in the triagular matrix rather than columnwise. For more information on that check the comments on the other answer.

Comment: I like your solution, too! Divakar's is even more precise and fully vectorized, so he gets the mark. I hope, you appreciate the upvote anyways